# How to catch entitydatasource exception

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, error-handling

I have a gridview that is bound to a entitydatasource.I've creaetd this using drag and drop from the asp.net controls in the toolbox, and using an entity data model.I have had little input in the codebehind. For testing purposes I have edited the gridview and added data that is invalid. I've then clicked update to cause an exception.

So my question is I would like to try and catch the exception in my own error handler  but I don't know where or how I can do this as I'm not sure which event I should be focusing on. I would just like to know where to begin with this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you won't able to given the form was designed using drag'n drop, declarative syntax. You are better off validating the user input before submitting it to the server. This should catch most exceptions.

your other option is to replace the declarative markup with code in the code behind where you can catch exceptions or call validation prior to calling `SaveChanges()`;

Answer (score 4):

You can trap the exception in the OnUpdated event of the EntityDataSource:

```
protected void EntityDataSource1_OnUpdated(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Exception != null) 
   {
         // handle here
          e.ExceptionHandled = true;
   }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you can catch the exception in global.asax but it will show generic error.