# What happens between DataBinding and DataBound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

In my WebForms application I have a drop down list (DDL) with methods `Method_DataBinding` and `Method_DataBound`. When I open form with this DDL and it have some wrong data, it gives me an exception. I want to catch it but I can't understand, where to do it.

On the last line of method `Method_DataBinding` there is no error and it don't reach `Method_DataBound`, so error is somewhere between this methods. I can't understand where

```
<asp:DropDownList
    ID="SomeId"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceId="SomeDsId"
    OnDataBinding="Method_DataBinding"
    OnDataBound="Method_OnDataBound" />

protected void Method_DataBinding()
{
}

// Here betwen this two methods I have error, can't catch it

protected void Method_DataBound()
{
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of these methods and also share the error details?

Comment: Is it a `SqlDataSource`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18821908/difference-between-databound-databind/18822081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `SqlDataSource`(`EntityDataSource` [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631627/how-to-catch-entitydatasource-exception)) you can use the [`Updated` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updated?view=netframework-4.8):

```
protected void SomeDsId_OnUpdated(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Exception != null) 
   {
         // handle here
   }
}
```